# How do I align multi line text vertically with background image set for :before

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, pseudo-element

I have a list of elements with icons added as background for `:before`. The text coming under the image when the title length is large.

[image]

How can I made the word services just below consultancy?

```css
li>a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.submenu-icon:before {
  content: "";
  margin-right: 0px;
  background: url(/sites/all/themes/bootstrap_cck/images/sprites.png) no-repeat;
  background-size: 40em;
  background-position: -250px -184px;
  padding: 15px 40px 12px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 47px;
  width: 55px;
  height: 47px;
}
```

```html
<li class="first">
  <a href="Consultancy-professional-services" class="submenu-icon">Consultancy & Professional Services  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Do you realy have to use a before element for the icon ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` on `a` element.

```css
a {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.submenu-icon:before {
  content: "PSEUDO";
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="Consultancy-professional-services" class="submenu-icon">Consultancy & Professional Services  </a>
```

Or with background image it should look like this.

```css
a {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.submenu-icon:before {
  content: "";
  background: url('http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100211112757/dexter/de/images/2/27/System-search.png') no-repeat;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-size: contain;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<a href="Consultancy-professional-services" class="submenu-icon">Consultancy & Professional Services  </a>
```